# Cheap old android phones like iphone 6s for React Native development

Tags: android, smartphones, development, web-development

I'm looking for an android phone for react native development. I recently bought a iphone 6s for like 20€ and I'm pretty impressed by it's speed considering its so old.

Can you guys recommend any android phones, that are kinda the same fast or faster but don't cost much?

I was thinking about a google pixel 1 or so for maybe 50€ if I can find one, but maybe there is something better and cheaper?

Unfortunately the android emulator is just too damn slow and buggy on my 10 years old mac laptop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up buying a used Google Pixel 2 for like 100€ from a refurbish online shop.

What I didn't come up with when I created the post was to check geekbench mobile benchmarks.
I was trying to find a cheap android phone that is close as fast as the Iphone 6s.
But to my suprise, "good" android phones are pretty expensive!
Old used Iphones are much cheaper and more available!

I also didn't want a super cheap fucked up phone from like walmart or so.
I wanted something that I can rely on, that will work properly and has a proper screen with kinda accurate colours.